# How to get the days out of a string using Regular Expression in Python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'd like to get the days out of a string using Regular Expression. However, the days are not in order so I'm not sure what pattern should I use.

Here's the sample texts;

```
NO STANDING 11AM-7AM MON SAT
NO STANDING 11AM-7AM MON FRI
NO STANDING 11AM-7AM MON TUES WED
NO STANDING 11AM-7AM MON SUN
NO STANDING MON FRI 7AM-9AM
```

The results I want is

```
MON SAT
MON FRI
MON TUES WED
MON SUN
MON FRI
```

And each result is in each group. So I can iterate through the groups.

The regex as far as I got is this `(MON|TUES|WED|THURS|FRI|SAT|SUN)` but that would just be in one group.

Comment: What language/program/library/regex standard are you using

Comment: Does the time portion always end in AM or PM followed by a space?

Comment: yep it's followed by a space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\b((?:(?:MON|TUES|WED|THURS|FRI|SAT|SUN)\s*)+)(?=\s|$)
```

**RegEx Explanation:**

```
\b            - Match word boundary
(             - captured group #1 start
  (?:         - non-captured group 1 start
    (?:       - non-captured group 2 start
      MON|TUE - Match a single day
    )         - non-captured group 2 end
    \s*       - match 0 more spaces
  )           - non-captured group 1 end
  +           - Match 1 or more of days
)             - captured group #1 end
(?=\s|$)      - Lookahead to assert a space or line end after the days
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fO4zL8/2)

Comment: Aren't they in one group, which OP didn't want?

Comment: I interpret it as `MON TUES WED` in one group and `MON SUN` in another

Comment: Very nice. And much better than my answer (which, undoubtedly, is why you have 314,000 points). :)

Comment: @anubhava can you explain a bit how this regex works?

Comment: You already know `(?:MON|TUES|WED|THURS|FRI|SAT|SUN)` as it matches a single day. Then `\s*` after this matches 0 more spaces and by having this in a group `(...)` with `+` quantifier makes it match multiple days at the end of each string.

Comment: It's accepted but does not work given your new example where the days are before the hours range.  I have no doubt Mr. anubhava will have an update shortly :-)

Comment: I'd be really appreciated if @anubhava could update the answer. I deleted the $ but I get an extra space.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will give you what you want:

```
((MON|TUES|WED|THURS|FRI|SAT|SUN)( (MON|TUES|WED|THURS|FRI|SAT|SUN))*)
```

It uses the RegEx you provided as its starting point, and then uses the same group -- preceded by a space and repeating zero or more times -- to get all of the day names that appear on a single line.

[Click here for a RegEx101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/yV6xA4/1)

**Edit:** @anubhava posted an answer that is vastly superior to mine. I'm leaving mine in place in case it helps frame an understanding of regular expressions, but I recommend marking his answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that duplicates are not allowed, this expression with lots of repetitions is going to work:

```
(MON|TUES|WED|THURS|FRI|SAT|SUN)(?: (MON|TUES|WED|THURS|FRI|SAT|SUN))?(?: (MON|TUES|WED|THURS|FRI|SAT|SUN))?(?: (MON|TUES|WED|THURS|FRI|SAT|SUN))?(?: (MON|TUES|WED|THURS|FRI|SAT|SUN))?(?: (MON|TUES|WED|THURS|FRI|SAT|SUN))?(?: (MON|TUES|WED|THURS|FRI|SAT|SUN))?
```

Essentially it's your expression for the first capturing group, followed by optional

```
(?: (MON|TUES|WED|THURS|FRI|SAT|SUN))?
```

repeated six more times ([demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/mQ4uK4/1)).

If you knew the *relative* order of days, as in your example (i.e. if `MON` and `TUE` are *both* present, then `MON` would be ahead of `TUE` you could simplify your expression to this ([demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/iJ3iB8/1)):

```
(?:(MON)\s?)?(?:(TUES)\s?)?(?:(WED)\s?)?(?:(THURS)\s?)?(?:(FRI)\s?)?(?:(SAT)\s?)?(?:(SUN)\s?)?
```